# When to save the results of a pan gesture to NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer, nsuserdefaults

My iOS app recognises pan gestures and I want to save the results of the pan (moving an object onscreen) to NSUserDefaults.

My gesture recogniser method works on both StateChanged and StateEnded messages and it's in here that I write the new position of the object(as moved by the pan) to NSUserDefaults.

however, I understand that writing to NSUserDefaults may be quite expensive, and I'm really only interested in saving the new position when the user has finished the pan, so should I only save (synchronise) NSUserDefaults when I get a StateEnded message from the gesture recogniser?

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: why on earth would u do that?

Comment: you can't save your position in an ivar?

Comment: By ivar, do you mean a property? I do, but I'd like the value (plus others) to be saved so that on subsequent program launches, you return to the same state as when you left it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - saving NSUserDefaults isn't that expensive and you don;t want to be saving the state of a pan gesture before that gesture is finished anyway, so saving when you get the stateEnded message makes sense.